# Using Facebook connect in CodeIgniter

Tags: javascript, codeigniter, dom-events, facebook-php-sdk

I am trying to add Facebook connect on my website but I am experiencing lot of issues since Facebook moved to OAuth 2 protocol.

I would like users log in with their Facebook account and then, I would store their data in my database.

So I am using the Javascript SDK to catch the `auth.login` event and then redirect to my `fb_login` method which use Facebook PHP SDK.

But here is my first issue, most of the time, the `auth.login` event is not catch by the listener and so my method is not called.

Here is my “listener” Javascript code:

```
<div id="fb-root"></div>
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.fbAsyncInit = function() {
     FB.init({
      appId: '<?php echo $this->config->item('facebook_app_id'); ?>', 
      status: true,
      cookie: true, 
      xfbml: true,
      oauth: true
     });
     FB.Event.subscribe('auth.login', function(response) {
      [removed] = "<?php echo site_url('donateur/fb_signin'); ?>";
     });
     FB.Event.subscribe('auth.logout', function(response) {
      alert("Logout :(");
     });
     FB.Event.subscribe('auth.authResponseChange', function(response) {
      alert('The status of the session is: ' + response.status);
     });
       
    };
    (function() {
     var e = document.createElement('script'); e.async = true;
     e.src = document.location.protocol +'//connect.facebook.net/en_US/all.js';
     document.getElementById('fb-root').appendChild(e);
    }());
```

I would like to know if anyone has already experience this issue?

Does anybody has a “recent” doc about how to use Facebook connect in CodeIgniter?

Answer (score 0):

http://codeigniter.com/forums/viewthread/189744/

And this: http://www.dannyherran.com/2011/02/facebook-php-sdk-and-codeigniter-for-basic-user-authentication/

Comment: Hi, first, thanks for your help ! :)
This tutorial seems good for the PHP-SDK part, it will really help me.

But for the moment, I am not able to redirect the user on this method. I don't know why, but each time I am logging with my Facebook account, I catch "auth.logout" and not "auth.login" ... :-/

Comment: no problem, hope it helps you... but also try and google "codeigniter facebook"